# Teradata - "Read-Only" Database

Tags: teradata

Please let me know if it is possible to mark a database as "Read-Only" in Teradata? We are harvesting a particular database and need to make it as "Read-Only"

Comment: There's no simple way in-database besides revoking access rights. But tTe DBAs could apply a Workload Management filter rejecting any access not based on Select.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth I will check with my DBA based on these options